# Route-Me Offline Maps from Document Root

Tags: objective-c, ios, route-me

In my App, there is a offline Map presented from a sqlite file.

```
RMDBMapSource *mapSrc = [[RMDBMapSource alloc] initWithPath:@"map.sqlite"];
RMMapContents *contents = nil;
contents = [[RMMapContents alloc] initWithView:mapView tilesource:mapSrc];
```

The map.sqlite file is loaded from my resources and everything is displayed correct.

My Problem: I am downloading new versions of the map.sqlite to my Apps documents folder.
How can I load my MapSource from a file in the documents folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How to implement this Route-me offline maps can u guide me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to write:

```
RMDBMapSource *mapSrc = [[RMDBMapSource alloc]  initWithPath:@"../Documents/yourdb.sqlite"];
```