# Using offline map sources with Monotouch's Route-me binding

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, route-me

I'm trying to get `route-me` to show an offline map which is bundled or to be downloaded after app installation. I'm using `route-me` bindings sample project to get the work done just for now. I also use the `mbtiles` file from the original `route-me` repo's `SampleMap` project. I copy the file to project's root directory and set it's build action to `BundleResource` (that's what I thought would be appropriate). After that I changed to code to this :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{ 
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    RMDBMapSource dbSource = new RMDBMapSource ("Philadelphia.mbtiles");

    MapView = new RMMapView(View.Frame, dbSource.Handle);
    MapView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;

    if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale > 1.0)
        MapView.AdjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = true;

    Add (MapView);
}
```

But no luck. App runs in the simulator but showing only a grey background nothing more. So I need someone to help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong. I need to get it done this week since next week is the deadline for project. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually used offline tiles myself, but based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155714/route-me-offline-maps-from-document-root) it looks like you might need to put the RMDBMapSource into an instance of RMMapContents instead of directly into the MapView. So I'm thinking it would be something like this with Xamarin:

```
RMDBMapSource dbSource = new RMDBMapSource ("Philadelphia.mbtiles");

MapView = new RMMapView(View.Frame, new IntPtr());

RMMapContents contents = new RMMapContents (MapView.Handle, dbSource.Handle);
```

That assumes you have a wrapper binding for RMMapContents too which from the looks of it the bindings project does not have by default. You'd need to throw in a wrapper that at least defines the constructor.

[This page](http://susilon.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/offline-maps-in-ios-using-openstreetmap-and-route-me/) looks like it provides similar code (in Obj-C) towards the bottom.